# What language to use?

Tags: html, web, youtube

What language should  I use if i were to write a script to for example download every video from a specific youtube channel as a mp3 file via http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ ? This has been on my mind for a very long time and it would be nice if anyone could answer this question. I know it should be possible with html to use the  tag and do some things with JS but i want a simpler and more reliable way. Thnx. PS. examples appreciated

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use c# with webclient class

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile("http://google.com", "a.mpeg");
}
```

Comment: is there a similar class in Java or Python?